# If $\frac{1}{5-2(z+z^{-1})}=f(z)+f(z^{-1})$with $f$ analytic at $z=0$, what is $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis

That is to say, the function $\frac{1}{5-2(z+z^{-1})}$ admits a Laurent expansion in $\frac{1}{2}<|z|<2$, and $f(z)$ being its analytic part (with half the constant term).

So what is the (close-form) expression of $f$?

I know the coefficients of $f$ can be computed using the Cauchy integral formula, but find evaluating those integrals rather tedious.

Are there any elementary method to solve this problem?

I have tried

$$\frac{1}{5-2(z+z^{-1})}=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n(z+z^{-1})^n}{5^n}=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{5^n}\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\binom{n}{k}(z^{n-2k}+z^{2k-n})$$

but could not go further.

Comment: If the singular part of the expression is $S(z)$, then you must have $f(z) = A(z)$ and $f(z^{-1}) = S(z)-A(z)$ for some analytic function $A$. Wonder if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I have just figured out an elementary answer.

Since $5-2(z+z^{-1})=(z-2)(z^{-1}-2)$, we could expect
$$\frac{1}{5-2(z+z^{-1})}=\frac{az+b}{z-2}+\frac{az^{-1}+b}{z^{-1}-2}$$
for some $a$ and $b$. This leads to
$$1=(az+b)(z^{-1}-2)+(az^{-1}+b)(z-2)=2(a-2b)+(b-2a)(z+z^{-1}).$$
So:
$$\begin{cases}a-2b=1/2\\ b-2a=0\end{cases}$$
which gives $a=-1/6$ and $b=-1/3$, and hence
$$f(z)=-\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{z+2}{z-2}$$